# Windows 8.1 powercfg.exe Power Settings Command-line Tool shows high CPU usage

Tags: windows-8.1, powercfg, high-cpu-usage

Recently I noticed my laptop fan was working harder, and there was this process using about 35% of CPU: `powercfg.exe Power Settings Command-line Tool`

I'm using Windows 8.1 and have never run that utility before myself.

The only noticeable change before this was that I installed CCleaner, did a cleanup and uninstalled it.

What I've done to fix the problem:

1. Updated Windows -> No result
2. Diagnostic startup -> The problem was gone

Update:
Today I noticed that even after ending the process, when the system was idle for a while, two instances of that process were back again and taking up to 50% of CPU.
[Task Manager snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emhVj.jpg)
[Details view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iO5iY.jpg)
Both of them where associated with this file:
"C:\Windows\System32\powercfg.exe"

How can I find what caused this problem? I have a restore point for a couple of days before this but the problem is that it says some of the programs and drivers I updated may not work correctly. Should I ignore it and just restore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restored the system and the problem has gone. Since there's been no other answer, I consider this the only solution. Two takeaways:

1. Don't turn off the restore point service of Windows. It can literally save you in such situations.
2. Keep away from CCleaner. It has a [history of being infected](https://www.kaspersky.com/resource-center/threats/ccleaner-malware) before.